# React; jszip not a constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, typescript-typings

In my project I work to export to excel my data. But i gave "jszip is not a constructor" error.
I tried npm install jsizip but it doesnt work
I try to configure webpack.config.js but this is very complextive for me.

it is my excel codes. I used here ExcelSheet I think problem is here bu i can not understand it.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Card, Form, Table } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { getData, getPosts } from '../data/apiData';
import { ScaleLoader } from 'react-spinners';

import ReactExport from 'react-data-export';

const ExcelFile = ReactExport.ExcelFile;
const ExcelSheet = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelSheet;

const HomeScreen = () => {

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [exportData, setExportData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const override = `
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-color: red
  `;

  const DataSet = [
    {
      columns: [
        { title: "Title", style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } }, width: { wpx: 125 } }, // width in pixels
        { title: "Body", style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } }, width: { wch: 30 } }, // width in characters
      ],
      data: exportData.map((data) => [
        { value: data.title, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: data.body, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
      ])
    }
  ]

  const getAllPosts = async () => {
    const data = await getPosts();
    setPosts(data);
  }

  const postChangeHandler = async (e) => {
    setExportData([]);
    setLoading(true);
    const data = await getData(e.target.value);
    console.log(data);
    setExportData([data]);
    setLoading(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllPosts();
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Card>
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>Excel Export</Card.Title>
          <Form>
            <Form.Control as="select" onChange={(e) => postChangeHandler(e)} defaultValue="Choose....">
              {posts.map(
                (post, i) =>
                  <option key={i} value={post.id}>{post.id}</option>
              )}
            </Form.Control>
          </Form>
          {exportData.length !== 0 ? (
            <ExcelFile
              filename="Covid-19 Data"
              element={<button type="button" className="btn btn-success float-right m-3">Export Data</button>}>
              <ExcelSheet dataSet={DataSet} name="Covid-19 Country Report" />
            </ExcelFile>
          ) : null}
          <Table responsive>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>title</th>
                <th>body</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {exportData.length === 0 ? (
                <tr>
                  <td colSpan="3">
                    <ScaleLoader
                      css={override}
                      size={150}
                      color={"#eb4034"}
                      loading={loading}
                    />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ) : (
                <>
                  {exportData.map((data) => (
                    <tr key={data.id}>
                      <td>{data.id}</td>
                      <td>{data.title}</td>
                      <td>{data.body}</td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </>
              )}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </div>
  )
}

export default HomeScreen
```